# Alert with integrated global condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to JQuery/JavaScript and need a jump start for below case:

Notifications (alert messages) can be useful for new users but annoying to experienced users. So I want to give my users the option to show or not show these messages depending on user setting.
In order not having to build the same condition (derived from the user setting) around every single alert, I would like to write a function that

- can be called with jquery in the script section of all my views
- evaluates the condition and takes the passed-in text and sends/does not send an alert message depending on the condition

I know how to build the condition around the alert, but fail to make it globally accessible:

```
var isConfirmActiv = "@UserPrincipal.ConfirmActiv";
var myMessage ="Bla bla";
if (isConfirmActiv.toLowerCase() === "true") {
    alert(myMessage);
}
```

I would like to use it in the script section of the view:

```
(var isConfirmActiv = "@UserPrincipal.ConfirmActiv";) ... somewhere?
myAlert("Bla bla", isConfirmActiv);
```

And in a script-file:

```
function myAlert(myMessage, isConfirmActiv){    
    if (isConfirmActiv.toLowerCase() === "true") {
    alert(myMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related, but you should use `var isConfirmActiv = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(UserPrincipal.ConfirmActiv))` which means `isConfirmActiv` will be a bool, so you can just use `if (isConfirmActiv) { ... }`

Comment: Place the variable in your _Layout.cshtml file in the `head` section, then you can access it in any of your views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create javascript file and name it Utility for example.

place your function and the global variable isConfirmActiv inside that file and link the js file to all views or to the master layout.

```
 var isConfirmActiv;

    function myAlert(myMessage, isConfirmActiv){    
        if (isConfirmActiv.toLowerCase() === "true") {
        alert(myMessage);
        }
    } 

- set directly the global defined isConfirmActiv value in every View in the script section (Note: don't redefine it, its already defined globally in javascript file)

    isConfirmActiv = "@UserPrincipal.ConfirmActiv";

- Now you can call the function from anywhere in your project.

    function myAlert(myMessage, isConfirmActiv){    
        if (isConfirmActiv.toLowerCase() === "true") {
            alert(myMessage);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You must define this var in the global scope (outside a function):

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

For example:

```
 var isConfirmActiv = "@UserPrincipal.ConfirmActiv";
 function myAlert(string myMessage){        
        if (isConfirmActiv.toLowerCase() === "true") {
            return alert(myMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But where do I place the function?